# Angular2 - Pipes and syntax

Tags: typescript, angular

Im trying to create a lowercase pipe in angular2 and im running into issues where Im getting

```
 syntax errors got ';'
```

*app/lowercase.ts*

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({ name: 'lowercase1'})
export class LowerCasePipe1 implements PipeTransform {

  transform (value: string): string {
    if (!value) return value;
    if (typeof value !== 'string'){
      throw new Error('Invalid pipe value: ', value);
    }
    return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

*app/app.component.ts*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LowerCasePipe1} from './lowercase';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
    pipes: [LowerCasePipe1],
    template: '<h1>{{"SAMPLE" | lowercase1 }} </h1>'
})
export class App {
  console.info('lower case app')
}
```

*app/index.ts*

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app.component';
//

bootstrap(App)
```

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/coB5AGWvpihUvCnBtX9D?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `system.config.js` file.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOOUrwpi2Gat4y4QsRIg?p=preview) built from the Plunker Angular2 TS template works fine.